# Changing variables from one module doesn't affect the variables passed to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class in one file1, which uses variables (that are constantly changing) from file2 but the changes are not being applied in the original class:

```
class element():
    def __init__(self, x, y)
        animations = [pic1, pic2, pic3]
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pos = pos
        self.atts = atts
    def update()
        ...

file2:

x = 100
y = 100
pos = 10
atts = ['red', '#122']

el1 = element(x,y)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Value types such as the parameters used in x and y are copied when passed as an attribute so if you change them in your second module, the change will not be applied in your object, so you will need to either update them again:

```
x = 100
y = 100
pos = 10
atts = ['red', '#122']

el1 = element(x, y, pos, atts)

x = 50

el1.x = x
```

Or you can use a reference type (another object) that you can share between the two files to wrap the value types:

```
class ElementConfig():
     def __init__(self, x, y, pos, atts):
         self._x = x
         self._y = y
         self._pos = pos
         self._atts = atts

     @property
     def x(self):
         return self._x

     @x.setter
     def x(self, value):
         self._x = value

     @property
     def y(self):
         return self._y

     @y.setter
     def y(self, value):
         self._y = value

     @property
     def pos(self):
         return self._pos

     @pos.setter
     def pos(self, value):
         self._pos = value
     
     @property
     def atts(self):
         return self._atts

     @atts.setter
     def atts(self, value):
         self._atts = value

class Element():
    def __init__(self, config: ElementConfig):
        self._config = config

    @property
    def config(self):
        return self._config
```

And in the other module:

```
from file1 import ElementConfig, Element

elementConfig = ElementConfig(100, 100, 10, ['red', '#122'])

el1 = Element(elementConfig)

print(el1.config.x)
```

The result is `100`

```
elementConfig.x = 200

print(el1.config.x)
```

Now the result is `200`

Comment: what I mean is that these variables actually change in file2,  x and y and the other variables will be constantly changing